# URL rewriting 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am beginner in rewriting url. I tried to do simple rewrite but it goes badly. I don't know why. Searched for answers but did not find anything.

Error I am encountering:

> **500 internal server error | Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

My `htaccess` file is in `/admin/.htaccess`
And I have another in `/.htaccess` - in this I have this code: `Options -Indexes`

```
# Rewriting URLs
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^custom dashboard.php [NC, L]
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What does the error log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without space in [NC, L]:

```
# Rewriting URLs
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^custom dashboard.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Not Found

I removed space, and there is another error.

The requested URL /admin/custom was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.